# How to replace similar values in the dataframe column properly?

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I have the string column `'Grade'` from dataframe with the following available values: 'A++', 'A+', 'A', 'A-','B++'. And I'd like to convert the whole column *(for `MinMaxScaler()` method)* accordingly to the following values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. 
I tried some solution, but don't get how to do it properly.
Could you, please, recommend a better solution?
Here's the code:

```
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].replace(to_replace='[A++]', value='0', regex=True)
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].replace(to_replace='[A+]', value='1', regex=True)
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].replace(to_replace='[A]', value='2', regex=True)
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].replace(to_replace='[A-]', value='3', regex=True)
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].replace(to_replace='[B+]', value='4', regex=True)
```

Here 's the result:
[replace result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTU1N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary together with `replace`, so quoting the vignette:

> For a DataFrame nested dictionaries, e.g., {'a': {'b': np.nan}}, are
>   read as follows: look in column ‘a’ for the value ‘b’ and replace it
>   with NaN. The value parameter should be None to use a nested dict in
>   this way. You can nest regular expressions as well. Note that column
>   names (the top-level dictionary keys in a nested dictionary) cannot be
>   regular expressions.

So you need to look for column 'Grade', and in the dictionary, lhs would be the grade to replace, RHS the value:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Grade':["A++","A+","A-","A","B+","A++","A-","B+"]})
df.replace({'Grade': {'A++': 0,'A+': 1,'A-': 3,"A":2,'B+': 4}})

   Grade
0   0
1   1
2   3
3   2
4   4
5   0
6   3
7   4
```

Comment: But then it will left only 5 records:
_0    A++
1     A+
2     A-
3      A
4     B+_
.I checked it by `print(df['Grade'])`

Comment: who do you mean? You have to write over the data frame, df = df.replace({'Grade': {'A++': 0,'A+': 1,'A-': 3,"A":2,'B+': 4}})

Comment: I mean that it doesn't return the whole column with all values but only 5 records :( even if I write over the df.

Comment: see above.. it should give you all the records. is there something different about your data frame?